# SQL: Troubles with GROUP BY today

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I'm super rusty when it comes to this. Actually, the way I'm imagining it in my head it sounds easy, but when I start writing it out I'm getting varied results.

Here's the ask:
Run a report showing all the account keys with their booklet type that don't have a WIP version.

Background:
Each account key in our system has 9 different booklet types. Each one of those types has a status. Status can be (3) Awaiting Approval, (4) Approved, (5) Work in Progress, or (8) Rejected.

Sample data with results:
[image]

From this screenshot you can see that all the booklet types EXCEPT 'Self Registeration' do NOT have a (5) Work in Progress. Those need to be on the report I'm trying to get.

Another example to explain what I'm trying to obtain:
[image]

Same query just with a different account key. You can see that the AIP has status (5) Work in Progress listed 3x, so this would NOT show on the report I'm trying to gather.

Below is the code I've tried but doesn't seem to work:

```
select b.trackingid, b.bookletname from booklet b
inner join [status] s on s.id = b.statusid
inner join [user] u on b.createdby = u.id
inner join client c on u.clientid = c.id
where c.clientname = 'MM' and
(select count(*) from booklet where trackingid = b.trackingid and statusid = 5) = 0
```

I've also tried using GROUP BY and HAVING:

```
select trackingid, b.bookletname, b.StatusID from booklet b
inner join [user] u on u.id = b.userid
inner join [client] c on c.id = u.clientid
where c.id = 2
--and b.statusID != 5
group by trackingid, bookletname, b.StatusID
--having count(statusid) < 1
order by trackingid
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try `and b.statusID <> 5` in your where clause.

Comment: Your question has lots of examples and screenshots but I am confused - I still have no idea what it is that you are trying to do. Can you provide a sample of the output you expect?

Comment: When you say `so this would NOT show` you are refering to just that tree marked registries or all the AIP that have the same `trackingId`?

Comment: Sorry it's confusing. Basically there are 200000+ records in this table. I just need the ones that haven't ever seen 5 (Work in Progress). In the one screenshot it shows 51000-1-1 having 5 (in the status field) three times so this would not be on the output, whereas on the first screenshot all but Self Registration would be on the report since none of those other booklet types have ever seen a 5.

Comment: Than you just need to add on your query the suggestion given by Andrew.

Comment: Example output:

http://imgur.com/G1BWuFL

Comment: What's the diff between != and <> ?

Answer (score 1):

When I am trying to report on datasets with lots of rows per key I am looking at, I like to generate a list of keys using a with; that way your main query doesn't have to look at anything else.
 so a couple of examples might look like:

```
; with wips as (
        Select Distinct trackingid
    From    booklet
    Where   statusid = 5
    ),
    nowips as(
    Select Distinct trackingid nwtid
    From    booklet
    Where   TrackingID not in (select * from wips)
    )
Select  <what ever you need>
From    Booklet
Join    nowips on TrackingID=nwtid
Where   <additional logic>
```

and

```
; with nowips as(
    Select Distinct trackingid nwtid
    From    booklet
    Where not exists (
            Select Distinct trackingid wtid
        From    booklet
        Where   statusid = 5
        and     wtid = nwtid)
    )
Select  <what ever you need>
From    Booklet
Join    nowips on TrackingID=nwtid
Where   <additional logic>
```

That should help eliminate the wip data from your report.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
--returns all bookletname not in status_id = 5
SELECT 
     trackingid
    ,b.bookletname
    ,b.StatusID
    ,count(*)
FROM booklet b
INNER JOIN [user] u ON u.id = b.userid
INNER JOIN [client] c ON c.id = u.clientid
WHERE c.id = 2
    AND b.statusid <> 5
GROUP BY trackingid, b.bookletname,b.statusid

UNION

--returns bookletnames = 'Self Registration and b.statusid = 5
SELECT 
     trackingid
    ,b.bookletname
    ,b.StatusID
    ,count(*)
FROM booklet b
INNER JOIN [user] u ON u.id = b.userid
INNER JOIN [client] c ON c.id = u.clientid
WHERE c.id = 2
    AND b.statusid = 5
    AND b.bookletname = 'Self Registration'
GROUP BY trackingid, b.bookletname,b.statusid
ORDER BY trackingid
```

This should return combination of both bookletname where statusid <> 5 including where self registration and statusid = 5. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You want to exclude a `trackingid` if there's any row with a `statusID=5`?
Do a conditional count using CASE:

```
select trackingid, b.bookletname 
from booklet b
inner join [user] u on u.id = b.userid
inner join [client] c on c.id = u.clientid
where c.id = 2
group by trackingid, bookletname
having sum(case when b.statusID = 5 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```